# Необходимо написать рекурсивную функцию Pch(), которая выдаёт количество простых чисел, меньше заданного. Например, Pch(100) = 25, Pch(7) = 2 и т.д

Tags: c++, функции, рекурсия

Необходимо написать рекурсивную функцию Pch(), в которую мы передаём некоторое число и она выдаёт нам количество простых чисел, меньше этого введённого числа. Например Pch(100) = 25, Pch(7) = 2 и т.д.
Нет проблемы в том, что бы сделать такую функцию, которая бы принимала 2 аргумента, один из которых счётчик простых чисел (k), а другой - уменьшенное на 1 заданное число (n). Например:

```
int Pch(int n, int&k)
```

{

```
int m = 0;
bool isPrime = true;

if (n == 1)
{
    return 0;
}

for (int i = 2; i <= (sqrt(abs(n))); i++) {
    if (n % i == 0)
    {
        isPrime = false;
        break;
    }
}

if (isPrime)
{
    cout << "n = " << n << "; ";
    k += 1;
}

n -= 1;
Pch(n, k);
return 0;
```

}

Но вопрос, как сделать такую функцию, что бы она принимала только 1 аргумент? Разве это возможно?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно. Набросок:

```
int Pch(int n)
{
    if (n == 1) return 0;
    return Pch(n-1) + isPrime(n);
}
```

Проверку на простоту `isPrime(n)` напишите самостоятельно, вы уже эту задачу решали...